# $ E[Y| {F}_{\leq t}]= E[Y]$ for Markov process

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $ X_s, ~ s\in [0,\infty) $ be a real valued stochastic process with the Markov property. That is

$$ E[Y| {F}_{\leq t}]=E[Y| {F}_{= t}]$$

Where $ Y $ is $ {F}_{\geq t} $-measurable, and ${F}_{\leq t} ,{F}_{= t},      {F}_{\geq t} $ are the sigma algebras generated by the respective sets of  $X_s$.

Now if   $ Y $ is $ {F}_{\geq u} $-measurable, for some $ u > t $, then it seems like we should have

$$ E[Y| {F}_{\leq t}]= E[Y]$$.  Is that true and how to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-example: take $X_t=tX, Y=X_u=uX$ where $X$ is a fixed non-constant random variable.